# How to display and refresh multiple lines in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a installation script and would like to display the status of the script as it progresses.

example:

```
var1="pending"
var2="pending"
var3="pending"

print_status () {
echo "Status of Item 1 is: "$var1""
echo "Status of Item 2 is: "$var2""
echo "Status of Item 3 is: "$var3""
}

code that does something and then refreshes the
output above as the status of each variable changes.
```

Comment: Try `clear`. It erases the screen. For more advanced tricks, use something like `dialog`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "refreshes"? Do you mean you want to have some "form" or "screen" of output where only certain fields update? And that there may be multiple such fields at a given time? Or does status of item2 only start after item1 has completed (and likewise item3 after item2)?

Answer (score 30):

This code should give you the idea:

```
while :; do
    echo "$RANDOM"
    echo "$RANDOM"
    echo "$RANDOM"
    sleep 0.2
    tput cuu1 # move cursor up by one line
    tput el # clear the line
    tput cuu1
    tput el
    tput cuu1
    tput el
done
```

Use `man tput` for more info. To see the list of capabilities use `man terminfo`

Comment: Though if you plan to go wild with this stuff, I'd recommend curses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)

Answer (score 7):

I find another solution which is not mentioned in existing answers. I am developing program for openwrt, and `tput` is not available by default. The solution below is inspired by [Missing tput](https://forum.archive.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=51278) and [Cursor Movement](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

```
- Position the Cursor:
  \033[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \033[<L>;<C>f
  puts the cursor at line L and column C.
- Move the cursor up N lines:
  \033[<N>A
- Move the cursor down N lines:
  \033[<N>B
- Move the cursor forward N columns:
  \033[<N>C
- Move the cursor backward N columns:
  \033[<N>D

- Clear the screen, move to (0,0):
  \033[2J
- Erase to end of line:
  \033[K

- Save cursor position:
  \033[s
- Restore cursor position:
  \033[u
```

As for your question:

```
var1="pending"
var2="pending"
var3="pending"

print_status () {
    # add \033[K to truncate this line
    echo "Status of Item 1 is: "$var1"\033[K"
    echo "Status of Item 2 is: "$var2"\033[K"
    echo "Status of Item 3 is: "$var3"\033[K"
}

while true; do 
    print_status
    sleep 1
    printf "\033[3A"    # Move cursor up by three line
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this:

```bsh
while true; do echo -ne "`date`\r"; done
```

and this:

```bsh
declare arr=(
  ">...."
  ".>..."
  "..>.."
  "...>."
  "....>"
)

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
  echo -ne "${i}\r"
  sleep 0.1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the carriage return to change text on a single status line.

```
n=0
while true; do
  echo -n -e "n: $n\r"
  sleep 1
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

If you can put all your counters on one line

```
n=0
m=100
while true; do
  echo -n -e "n: $n  m: $m\r"
  sleep 1
  n=$((n+1))
  m=$((m-1))
done
```

This technique doesn't seem to scale to multiple lines, though it does have the benefit over tput that it works on dumb terminals (like Emacs shell).

Answer (score 0):

This does not completely solve your problem but might help; to print the status after the execution of each command, modify PS1 like this:

```
PS1='$PS1 $( print_status )'
```